# Which information is "destroyed" when a qubit is read?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

A quantum bit is a unit vector in $C^2$.  That is, a four dimensional unit vector.

A computational basis is a pair of orthogonal vectors in $C^2$ that you choose - say, [0, 1] and [1, 0].  So the computational basis forms a *2D* subspace of the *4D* space.

When you measure a qubit to obtain a vector in the computational basis, this projects the full 4D state down to a 2D value.  Is this why most of the information is said to be **destroyed** when the qubit is read?

(I'm reading http://jeremykun.com/2014/12/15/the-quantum-bit/, for reference)

EDIT: A computational basis is not a pair of orthogonal vectors.  It is a pair of pairs of vectors, all mutually orthogonal.

Comment: You go from two complex numbers (=4 real numbers) to a bit, not to 2 real numbers.  Your 4D->2D analogy is wrong.

Comment: Ahh, so when you measure a quantum bit, all you get is one classical bit.  You choose a basis (two pairs of orthonormal vectors) to measure along.  We may write the qubit as $\alpha|1\rangle + \beta |2\rangle$, expressing it in that basis.  When you measure the qubit, $1$ or $2$ is chosen probabilistically, based on $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  Does this mean that for practical quantum computation, you always want to choose your basis such that either $\alpha=1$ or $\beta=1$, so that you're "sure" about the information you get?

Comment: Exactly. Regarding your question: It depends. In many cases, it is favorable to have a unique answer in a quantum computation, but there are cases where one obtains a probabilistic outcome from which one can extract the right answer by classical postprocessing.

Comment: "EDIT: A computational basis is not a pair of orthogonal vectors. It is a pair of pairs of vectors, all mutually orthogonal." -- This makes no sense.

Comment: In my earlier comment I say "You choose a basis (two pairs of orthonormal vectors) to measure along. We may write the qubit as $ \alpha |1 \rangle + \beta |2\rangle$, expressing it in that basis."  That's what I'm referring to in the edit.  Does that make sense?

Comment: A measurement basis (for $\mathbb C^2$) is a pair of orthogonal vectors. The so-called *computational* basis is just a specific choice for these two vectors. (Guess I did not read that part of your comment carefully enough.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a single-qubit:

$|\psi\rangle=\alpha|1\rangle+\beta|2\rangle$

$\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}=1$ and $\langle1|2\rangle=0$

The states $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ are the orthonormal basis states of the two-state system. The quantum information is stored in the amplitudes $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

A single measurement of the system only reveals $|1\rangle$ or $|2\rangle$ with probabilities $|\alpha|^{2}$ and $|\beta|^{2}$ and the measurement will collapse the state vector $|\psi\rangle$ on to one of these basis states. So repeated measurements permit the determination of $|\alpha|^{2}$ and $|\beta|^{2}$, but not about $\alpha$ or $\beta$. i.e, to determine $\alpha$ or $\beta$ an infinite number of measurements have to be made since they are complex numbers. So the quantum information is hidden and a large part of it is lost during measurement.

In quantum computation, we only manipulate the qubits and let them interact with each other coherently without making measurements. So all the information will be preserved during computation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So when you measure the qubit, it goes to some orthogonal basis; you can't choose which. Is it 50-50, or do $\alpha$ and $\beta$ tell you the probabilities it'll go to $|1\rangle$ or $|2\rangle$ respectively?

Are $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ the ONLY bases it could go to - are they fixed relative to the quantum computer?

One more thing: If the qubit goes to $|1\rangle$, you can know $\alpha$.  But $|1\rangle$ is itself a 2D space with a unit vector lying on it. Couldn't you actually know two numbers: $\alpha$, and the one degree of freedom the qubit has within $|1\rangle$?

Comment: and yes, this does help ;)

Comment: This is incorrect. Measuring your qubit and finding a result of $|1\rangle$ does not tell you what $\alpha$ is besides telling you that it is non-zero.

Comment: I second that, the answer is incorrect. Don't understand why it got upvoted.

Comment: The answer is still incorrect after the edit.  Repeated measurements do **not** allow to determine $|\alpha|^2$ and $|\beta|^2$, **except** if we have **many copies** of the state, which is an entirely different scenario.